# Subversion 1.9.7 merging trunk into branch gives me Syntax error in revision argument 'LastRevisionMergedFromTrunkToBranch:HEAD'

Tags: svn

Im using Ubuntu 17.10 and Subversion 1.9.7. I try to merge my Trunk code into Branch code.

```
svn merge -rLastRevisionMergedFromTrunkToBranch:HEAD https://someurl.com/system/trunk/ ~/IdeaProjects/svn/system/branches/system-1.27
```

Error message:

> svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument 'LastRevisionMergedFromTrunkToBranch:HEAD'

Answer (score 1):

LastRevisionMergedFromTrunkToBranch should be a revision number, the string itself has no meaning for SVN.

Example:

```
svn merge -r24356:HEAD https://someurl.com/system/trunk/ ~/IdeaProjects/svn/system/branches/system-1.27
```